# Assign $pwd to $PATH variable conditionally

Tags: osx, zsh, path

I want to add my current working directory with its project-specific `bin` directories to my $PATH when the directories are present.

So I added these lines to my **.zshrc**:

```bsh
[ -d "$(pwd)/vendor/bin" ] && export PATH="$(pwd)/vendor/bin":"$PATH"
[ -d "$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin" ] && export PATH="$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin":"$PATH"
```

The upper paths are prepended when I manually paste the commands to the terminal but otherwise they aren't. The `$PATH` is the same as before. I also tried different ways to write it like `"${PATH}"` and the zsh `path` function. They all do work when pasted manually but not when inside the **.zshrc** file.

--

I'm on *macOs High Sierra v10.13.6* with the *default Terminal* and using *zsh v5.7.1*.

Comment: Your `rc` file is not executed from the directory you want it to.  It's also bad practice to add `pwd` to your `PATH`.  Why not just specify the full path you desire in your `PATH`?

Comment: Well I thought `pwd` prints the full current path? I have many different projects and I don't want to paste them all manually. So whenever the directories are there I'd like to have them in my `PATH`. Why would that be bad practice?

Comment: Sure but your rc file isn't sourced every time you change directories, only once per shell session.  The pwd at that time is likely your `$HOME` directory.  It's likely not as big of an issue when you specify subdirectories after it but you don't want `pwd` in your `PATH` because you don't want to accidentally run programs that may be in the current directory that share the names of other programs in your bin directories.  Also as you have found it simply doesn't work the way you want it to.

Comment: Could you make "doesn't work" more explicit? Does it execute with errors? Does it not (appear) execute at all?

Comment: @Jesse_b Oohh of course. Okay I get it now. Thanks!
I'm also using `oh-my-zsh` so maybe a plugin will do then.

Comment: Just use a path relative to your `$HOME` rather than `$(pwd)`.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` specifically, you could do:

```
path[1,0]=( ~/projects/{vendor/,node_modules/.}bin(/N) )
```

Where:

```
path[1,0]=( list )
```

inserts the `list` at the start of the array (`$path` in `zsh` is an array tied to `$PATH` like in `csh`).

and `(N/)` is a glob qualifier where `N` enables `nullglob` for the glob and `/` selects files of type directory, so it add those two files ahead of `$PATH` provide they exist and are of type *directory*.

`pwd` is the command that `p`rints the current `w`orking `d`irectory (the contents of the `$PWD` variable), it would only make sense to use `$(pwd)`, or rather `$PWD` in your `.zshrc` if you wanted to add directories to `$PATH` conditionally to where `zsh` is started from. But even then, that would be dangerous, as for instance, if you started `zsh` from `/tmp` or someone else's directory, someone could have planted malicious files there that override standard commands such as `ls` or `rm`.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think its possible to do it as you want, not with .rc (.rc is executed only once, it will not be executed later unless you specifically do it). But what about two aliases?

```
backupPATH=$PATH
function mkpath {
    [ -d "$(pwd)/vendor/bin" ] && export PATH="$(pwd)/vendor/bin":"$PATH"
    [ -d "$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin" ] && export PATH="$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin":"$PATH"
}
alias resetpath="PATH=$backupPATH"
```

With that you can add your current directory to the $PATH at any time.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, your code does not necessarily work as you expect when you open a new terminal, as the current working directory may not be the one that contains your projects, and that piece of code is *only* run when a new shell starts.

Instead, you presumably know where your projects are, possibly in relation to your `$HOME` directory.  If so, you may use that instead:

```
for binpath in vendor/bin node_modules/.bin; do
    if [ -d "$HOME/projects/$binpath" ]; then
        PATH=$HOME/projects/$binpath:$PATH
    fi
done

export PATH
```

Here, I'm assuming that `$HOME/projects` is where your projects are.

The `export` at the end is probably not needed as `PATH` is likely exported already.